# IE 10 cross origin requests on SAP Netweaver

Tags: cors, javascript, sapui5

I was using openUI5 as reference to develop my applications  ( downloaded the library and referring local version in my application )
Now i have a need to refer sap.viz library in my application and i figured sap.viz is not part of openUI5 .

So, i started to refer library from remote host like below :

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"    
    type="text/javascript"   
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3,sap.m,sap.viz"   
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"   
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js">    
</script>
```

I have deployed my application on SAP MII ( Netweaver java based ) .

The application doesn't work in IE 0 but it works fine in Chrome.  When i researched it is to do with CORS (cross origin requests ) . I tried to define Content-security-policy to ignore this using below code but it doesn't help .

```
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com"/>  
<meta  http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com"/>
```

I have created sample code using http://jsbin.com/cigorepiri/1/edit

Error i received in IE10 while debuuging is

```
SCRIPT5022: failed to load 'sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery-mobile-custom.js' from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery-mobile-custom.js: 0 - [object Error]
```

So, either i need a solution to ignore this by IE10  OR Need a way to download sap.viz libary .

Please advice.

Thanks
Hari

Comment: I was problems compatibility view settings. when i removed the that host of list and un checked box "display intranet sites in compatibility view"

Answer (score 0):

Configure your web.xml with code shown below. Include your domain under com.sap.ui5.proxy.REMOTE_LOCATION

```
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- UI5 proxy servlet                                              -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sap.ui5.proxy.SimpleProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/proxy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sap.ui5.proxy.REMOTE_LOCATION</param-name>
        <param-value>YOUR DOMAIN (INCLUDE PORT NUMBER if any) </param-value>
    </context-param>
```